# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' | Beautifulsoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.8

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession

#Request URL
page = requests.get('https://www.fifa.com/worldcup/players.html')

#Fetch webpage
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")  

player_age = soup.find("div",{"class":"fi-p__profile number__number"}).text.replace("\n","").strip()
print(player_age)
```

Error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: where did you find that url? it's invalid. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please find the correct url : https://www.fifa.com/worldcup/players/, I am trying to extract the each player information like player name, country, age etc

Comment: did you not see my solution below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ok. I see. You have the url wrong. First, you need to drop the `.html`. Secondly, you'll need to find the urls that can actually fetch you the data. Unfortunately there is no API endpoint (that I can see here) to get you the player data.

So slightly different approach is to access each player profile and pull it that way. But in order to get to the player profile, you need the playerID to iterate through. This will take a while to run, since it needs to pull from each player profile/url, but gets the job done:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.87 Safari/537.36'}

#Get playerIDs
url = 'https://www.fifa.com/worldcup/players/_libraries/byposition/all/_players-list'
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,"html.parser")  

playerIDs = soup.find_all('a', {'class':'fi-p--link '})
playerDict = {}
for player in playerIDs:
    name = player.find('div',{'class':'fi-p__name'}).text.strip()
    playerID = player['data-player-id']

    playerDict[name] = playerID


for player_name, playerID in playerDict.items():
    #Request URL
    url = 'https://www.fifa.com/worldcup/_libraries/players/player/%s/_player-profile-data' %playerID
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    #Fetch webpage
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,"html.parser")  
    player_age = soup.find('div',{'class':'fi-p__profile-number__number'}).text.strip()

    print('%-20s Age: %s' %(player_name, player_age))
```

**Output:**

```
Aaron MOOY           Age: 29
ABDALLA SAID         Age: 34
Abdiel ARROYO        Age: 26
Abdoulaye DIALLO     Age: 27
ABDULLAH ALKHAIBARI  Age: 23
ABDULLAH ALMUAIOUF   Age: 33
ABDULLAH OTAYF       Age: 27
Abdullahi SHEHU      Age: 26
ABDULMALEK ALKHAIBRI Age: 33
Abel AGUILAR         Age: 35
Achraf HAKIMI        Age: 21
Adama MBENGUE        Age: 26
Adem LJAJIC          Age: 28
Adil RAMI            Age: 34
Adnan JANUZAJ        Age: 25
Adolfo MACHADO       Age: 34
ADRIEN SILVA         Age: 30
AHMED ELMOHAMADY     Age: 32
AHMED FATHI          Age: 35
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Error says us that `soup.find("div",{"class":"fi-p__profile number__number"})` found nothing. And nothing (None or NoneType) can't have any attributes.

By the way, link you provided returns 404 error. It seems like you try to parse page without requested data.